# Time offsetting 2 hours after suspend

Tags: 20.04, time

My computer had a suspend issue, where it couldn't resume from it. I tried several things and finally, it worked.

The thing is that, I tried many debugging strategies, and I remember specifically that one of those offsets the time when there is a suspend. So now, every time I suspend, it does that: the time is offset 2 hours from the correct time. To be honest, I don't remember what I did nor the page where I followed the instructions. I can't find it either.

Edit: Debugging used `pm_trace`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm puzzled at your question though: If you can't remember what you did, how do you expect any of us here to guess it out of thin air?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I'm really sorry. I know this is a hail mary. I'm trying to find the process of the debugging that I did, but the browser history got deleted :(

Comment: One suggestion I can think of is possibly a script that you might have added to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` directory that is ran after the system sleeps.  Or, run `history` from your terminal window and see if any commands there might look familiar with what you did to change the time offset.